# How to understand the .hdf5 file annotations for ShanghaiTech A and B?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision

I am looking at the ShanghaiTech A and B datasets which are used for crowd counting
which can be found at this link https://github.com/desenzhou/ShanghaiTechDataset
I notice that each image is accompanied with a .mat file and a .hdf5 file.

**.mat file**
The .mat file contains coordinates of each head as well as the ground truth.
For example for image 1

```
coordinates are [[ 29.6225116  472.92022152]
 [ 54.35533603 454.96602305]
 [ 51.79045053 460.46220626]
 ...
 [597.89732076 688.27900015]
 [965.77518336 638.44693908]
 [166.9965574  628.1873971 ]]
```

as well as a ground truth value of 1546

**.hdf5 file**

On the other hand, the .hdf5 file contains several keys

```
['attention', 'density', 'gt']
```

Using the keys, i extract the data like that

```
#extrating data 
attention_data = f.get('attention')
print("attention shape:" , attention_data.shape)
attention_data = np.array(attention_data) # For converting to a NumPy array
print("sum of attention data:", attention_data.sum())
```

These turns out to be 768x1024 arrays containing values, as illustrated below

- Attention contains decimal values ranging from 0 to 0.05ish
- Density contains values of only 0 OR 1

```
attention shape: (768, 1024)
sum of attention data: 132021.0
density shape: (768, 1024)
sum of density data: 1545.0001
density_data * attention_data IS 1530.4147
gt is 1546
gt is of type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Questions:

1. How may I understand the attention and density values ?
2. Why does an element-wise multiplication not yield the ground truth ?
3. How may I label additional images to add on to the dataset ?

Posts I have consulted to help decipher the dataset

1. [explain ground-thruth .mat file of an image for CNN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51030406/explain-ground-thruth-mat-file-of-an-image-for-cnn)
2. https://github.com/desenzhou/ShanghaiTechDataset

Edit:
3) I believe I may have found how the hdf5 file was generated. I had mistakenly thought it was hand-labelled. https://www.kaggle.com/code/tthien/shanghaitech-a-train-density-gen/script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found out...
to parse and understand the MAT file

```
import scipy
from scipy.io import loadmat
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cv2 

#specify your file directories here 
img_dir = "A1.jpg" 
matfile_dir = 'GT_IMG_1.mat'

#opening base image to draw on later 
input_image = cv2.imread(img_dir)

#loads the .mat file using scipy
matContent = scipy.io.loadmat(matfile_dir) 

#mat file is labelled in a certain array format. 
#array format goes ['image_info'][0][0][0][0][x], where x is any number 
# x = 0 gives the x,y coordinates of the points
# x = 1 gives the ground truth of the crowd count 

coordinates = matContent['image_info'][0][0][0][0][0] #extracts coordinates of heads 
print("coordinates are", coordinates)
```

To parse and understand the hdf5 files

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import h5py
f = h5py.File('A1.h5','r')
print(list(f.keys()))

for item in f: 
    print(item) #gets the keys and prints them out 
    continue

#you will see the keys attention, density and gt

#extrating data 
attention_data = f.get('attention')
print("attention shape:" , attention_data.shape)
attention_data = np.array(attention_data) # For converting to a NumPy array
print("sum of attention data:", attention_data.sum())
#print(attention_data)


density_data = f.get('density')
print("density shape:" , density_data.shape)
density_data = np.array(density_data) # For converting to a NumPy array
print("sum of density data:", density_data.sum())
#print(density_data)


density_times_attention = density_data * attention_data
total = density_times_attention.sum()
print("density_data * attention_data IS", total)
 

gt_data = f.get('gt')
gt_data = np.array(gt_data) # For converting to a NumPy array
print("gt is", gt_data)
print("gt is of type", type(gt_data))
```